# ExtJs , How to create Tracking/Steps Bar

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I want to create steps or tracking bar in Sencha ExtJS Classic as the following images

what is the best way to implement this in ExtJS Classic?

**each step have to be clickable**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Classic or Modern?

Comment: Classic , Updated in the Question

Answer (score 0):

You can start with:

*@example*: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/274i

Or you start your own like this:

```
xtype: breadcrumb
```

*example*: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/31vu

Other than that you can also start with the `segmentedbutton` and use css `::after` to add the colored line.

In the past I did this one time and it turned out to be a lot of work. We used `layout: 'hbox'` and used `button`s.

The main problem was to add the logic to allow step back still keeping information, add logic after each step separately and make this a full "wizard-component".

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, do you have an example, will be appreciated

Comment: I added an example for breadcrumb. You can manipulate it so that it shows all items and set items active and passive via store

Comment: thanks for the effort,  unfortunately, the first example `layout: card` which is the most suitable one do not keep the previous steps selected

Comment: Your question was: what is the best way to start. I took the time to present you several starting points. But it seems you wanted to have a fully functional result? You have to do some of the work yourself or pay someone to do the job. I told you it is a lot of work. All of my answers require that you add a card-layout for the content.